# Spring live reload for ThreadPoolExecutor

Tags: java, spring, multithreading

i am not really familiar with Spring's Live Reload feature. However, i noticed that every time i have changes saved on my Java code. Java profiles (JMC) or Eclipse's (Debug Mode) shows that the thread i already spawned was spawned again resulting on 2 threads (1 thread before reload + 1 thread after reload).

I am currently using `ThreadPoolExecutor` to spawned my threads. basically i am letting spring manage my threads. In this case, How to i force shutdown/interrupt the threads i spawned when there is live reload occuring?

[image]

Below is my source.

**ApplicationThreadingConfiguration.java**

```
@Configuration
public class ApplicationThreadingConfiguration {
    private static final Logger logger = LoggerFactory.getLogger(ApplicationThreadingConfiguration.class);

    @Autowired
    MyProperties prop;
    
    
    @Bean(name = "myThread")
    public TaskExecutor taskExecutor() {
        logger.info(prop.toString()); 
        final ThreadPoolTaskExecutor executor = new ThreadPoolTaskExecutor();
        executor.setCorePoolSize(prop.getCorePoolSize());
        executor.setMaxPoolSize(prop.getMaxPoolSize());
        executor.setQueueCapacity(prop.getQueueCapacity());
        executor.setThreadNamePrefix("MyThread-");
        executor.setWaitForTasksToCompleteOnShutdown(true);
        executor.initialize();
        return executor;
    }
    
}
```

**AppEventConfiguration.java** (this spawns my thread after Spring context is loaded)

```
@Configuration
public class AppEventConfiguration {
    private static final Logger logger = LoggerFactory.getLogger(AppEventConfiguration.class);
    
    @Autowired
    private MyService service;
    
    @Autowired
    private ApplicationContext context;
    
    @Autowired
    @Qualifier("myThread")
    private TaskExecutor executor;
    
    @EventListener(ApplicationReadyEvent.class)
    public void onApplicationReadyEvent() {
        service.getSomethingFromDB().stream().forEach(dto -> {
            logger.info("Id: {}", dto.getId());
            MyRunnableThread t = this.context.getBean(MyRunnableThread.class);
            t.setMyId(dto.getId());
            executor.execute(t); 
        });
    }
}
```

**MyRunnableThread.java**

```
@Component
@Scope("prototype")
public class MyRunnableThread implements Runnable {
    private static final Logger logger = LoggerFactory.getLogger(MyRunnableThread.class);
    
    private long myId;
    
    @Override
    public void run() {
        while(true) {
            try {
                logger.info("Do something here on ID: {}",this.myId);
                Thread.sleep(5000);
            } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    }

    public void setMyId(long id) {
        this.myId = myId;
    }
}
```

**myproperties.properties**

```
myprop.core-pool-size=80
myprop.max-pool-size=100
myprop.queue-capacity=100
```

Comment: Also show the properties used to configure the pool.

Comment: okay, please see udpated. Also, i've made a workaround however, this maybe kinda custom. If there is a built-in in spring. please do share